# Put iPhone to sleep programmatically, not an app for App Store

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The sleep button on my iPhone is no longer working. As a developer my idea is to create an app which will put the phone to sleep as soon as launched.

However, after searching SO it seems every answer has been that it involves private API's and that it won't make it to the App Store. As this is not intended for the App Store, how can this be done?

Comment: If you're willing to jailbreak it should be simple to load a custom app. Otherwise I think (I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure) that you would need to open a developer account with apple - whatever the cost of that may be.

Comment: Thought of getting the iPhone repaired or buying a new or second hand one?

Comment: I already have an account. Any ideas?

Comment: I will get it repaired, but this would be helpful before sending it away.

Comment: This isn't directly answering your question, but there's a jailbreak tweak called _Activator_ that can assign commands to particular buttons, e.g. you could have a triple-press of the home button lock the screen.